# How to find the `True` values' corresponding index and column in a large Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame `df` whose values are mostly `False`.

About 1% of the values of `df` are `True`.

How can I display the `True` values' corresponding index and column?

Here's the index of `df`

```
df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2007-04-23', '2007-04-24', '2007-04-25', '2007-04-26',
               '2007-04-27', '2007-04-30', '2007-05-02', '2007-05-03',
               '2007-05-04', '2007-05-07',
               ...
               '2021-02-24', '2021-02-25', '2021-02-26', '2021-03-02',
               '2021-03-03', '2021-03-04', '2021-03-05', '2021-03-08',
               '2021-03-09', '2021-03-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=3426, freq=None)
```

Here's the columns of `df`

```
df.columns
Index(['0015', '0050', '0051', '0052', '0053', '0054', '0055', '0056', '0057',
       '0058',
       ...
       '9944', '9945', '9946', '9949', '9950', '9951', '9955', '9958', '9960',
       '9962'],
      dtype='object', name='stock_id', length=1947)
```

And `df.shape` returns `(3426, 1947)`.

Suppose only the values of `df['1234']['2020-01-05']`, and `df['4321']['2020-03-07']` are true.

How can I write a function whose input is `df` and whose output are `df['1234']['2020-01-05']` and `df['4321']['2020-03-07']`?

Comment: `whose output are df['1234']['2020-01-05'] and df['4321']['2020-03-07']` aren't they just `True, True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need `DataFrame` use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series` and then filter `True`s with convert `MultiIndex` to `DataFrame` by [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html):

```
#data from @Quang Hoang answer
s = df.stack()

df1 = s[s].index.to_frame(index=False).set_axis(['idx','cols'], axis=1)
print (df1)
    idx cols
0  2010    a
1  2011    c
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have this:

```
# Test data
          a      b      c
2010   True  False  False
2011  False  False   True
```

You can try `np.where`:

```
x,y = np.where(df)
indexes = df.index[x]
columns = df.columns[y]
print(indexes, columns)
```

Output:

```
Index(['2010', '2011'], dtype='object') Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')
```